# How to remove triangular dots next to line numbers in RStudio code editor

Tags: r, rstudio

[image]

I'm uncertain how they got there but I have these small dots, which have a triangular shape just to the right of the line numbers in the RStudio code editor.  When I click on them they collapse the code.  They seem to occur where I have a bracket in the code.  I'm not sure whether they are interfering with calculations, but my code is not returning the right answers.  How do I get rid of these dots?

I have explored the menus but haven't found anything to remove these dots.  I've never noticed them before and I'm unsure what their purpose is but I'm trying to remove them, without any luck.  Can I remove them or are they a part of the editor that I haven't noticed before?

While I'm at it, this is the code I've been working with below:

It's from a book R for Dummies, I'm learning this language.  But the 2nd line is not calculating, consequently this throws the rest of it out.  I've tried re-writing it.  I'm a VBA programmer, but I'm brand new to R.  I haven't figured out how to debug in R as yet. The priceCalculator is straight out of the book, it "should" work, but doesn't.  Please help.enter code here

```
  priceCalculator <- function(hours, pph = 40, public = TRUE){ 

  net.price <- hours * pph     #This line is not calculating

  if(hours > 100) net.price <- net.price * 0.9

  if(public){
    tot.price <- net.price * 1.06
  } else {
  tot.price <- net.price * 1.12
  }
  round(tot.price)
}
```

Comment: The code collapsing feature most certainly does not interfere with your code.

Comment: I'm able to run the function fine.  `priceCalculator(100)` returns `4240`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

The triangular icons are in fact code-collapsing options that RStudio (not R the language) provides. You are correct, that they will act on curly braces (for example you can collapse the body of a function this way, helpful to get a mental picture of your code...). It also works on some code comments (eg try inserting a code comment ending with `####` and it should be groupable/hideable by the triangles).

As Phil pointed out, they do not interfere with your code (except that its hidden for you), if you source the file or execute a chunk of code, the hidden code will be included in it!

Regarding your coding question: as you didn't provide any execution command but just the function definition, I cannot say why it wasn't working, I guess you provided a wrong or no input for `hours`.
Regardless, check out the code below

```r
priceCalculator <- function(hours, pph = 40, public = TRUE){ 
  net.price <- hours * pph
  
  if(hours > 100) net.price <- net.price * 0.9
  
  if(public){
    tot.price <- net.price * 1.06
  } else {
    tot.price <- net.price * 1.12
  }
  round(tot.price)
}


priceCalculator(100)
#> [1] 4240

# playing around with the arguments
priceCalculator(110)
#> [1] 4198
priceCalculator(110, pph = 50)
#> [1] 5247
priceCalculator(110, pph = 50, public = FALSE)
#> [1] 5544
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>